# Identity for $4\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta\sin^2\gamma$ expressed as product of terms $(\pm\sin\alpha\pm\sin\beta\pm\sin\gamma)$

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request, triangles

It is well known (?) that if $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$ then $4\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma = \sin(2\alpha)+\sin(2\beta)+\sin(2\gamma)$ (I think I've seen it in some late-19th-century books, and I read somewhere on the internet (therefore it's true!! right?) that it has repeatedly appeared on the joint entrance examination of the Indian Institutes of Technology).

It seems very probable that this similar identity is in the literature somewhere, and I wonder **where**:
$$
\begin{align}
& {}\qquad \text{If }\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi\text{ then }4\sin^2\alpha\;\sin^2\beta\;\sin^2\gamma \\
& = (\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma)(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta-\sin\gamma)(\sin\alpha-\sin\beta+\sin\gamma)(-\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I have tagged it as reference-request.

Comment: Heron's formula + the law of sines?

Comment: @Hans: Looking at this now, I think there may be essentially nothing more involved than the two identities you mention.  Every few months I look at something I scrawled months ago about things like this and go on from where I left off without stopping to recall how I got there.  About three years ago I actually found the sum of the distances from the vertices of a triangle to the Fermat point a.k.a. the Steiner point.  Surprisingly hairy and I don't remember much about how I did it.  Everybody knows that point minimizes the sum; few if any know the _value_ of the sum.

Comment: ....as a function of the lengths of the three sides.

Comment: @Michael: I get $2m^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+4\sqrt{3s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ where $s=(a+b+c)/2$.

Comment: This would probably routine for a computer algebra package to verify by converting the trig functions into exponentials.

Comment: @Ragib: It would be, but, as shown, these are all simple consequences of the Law of Sines, the Law of Cosines, and Heron's Formula. Why invoke a CA package? I find proof by computer a little less satisfying.

Comment: @rob, true, I probably overreacted to the apparent complexity of the problem. I just have that sort of reaction to problems like this, where I know there is a completely algorithmic procedure for solving it. In the same vein, I don't particularly enjoy integrating rational functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using Heron's formula (*) as stated in the comments, but notice that this is simply the constraint (or the Zariski closure of the constraint) on the sines of three angles to be sines of a triangle. I don't think there is a lower-degree polynomial expressing the same condition.  This raises the question of whether a conceptual solution exists, avoiding the details of classical geometry.

[(*)  Start from Heron's formula (squared), replace Area by $abc/4R$, replace $a,b,c$ by $2R\sin \alpha, 2R \sin \beta, 2R \sin \gamma$.    Factors of $R$ will disappear from the final result, leaving the formula on sines.

The "well known" formula at the top of the question is a similar restatement of the fact that the area of a triangle is the sum of the small triangles formed by joining vertices to the center of the circumscribed circle.]

Comment: The areas of the small triangles are _signed_ areas.